# expr: non-numeric argument while calling script from another script and passing argument read from file

Tags: bash, shell

I have following code:

```
#!/bin/bash

PROP_FILE="${HOME}/my-prop.properties"

getProperty() {
        echo `cat ${PROP_FILE} | grep ${1} | cut -d'=' -f2`
}

PORT=$(getProperty "PORT")
HOSTS=$(getProperty "HOSTS")

#PORT=myPort
#HOSTS=myHosts

echo ${PORT}
echo ${HOSTS}

EXE="${HOME}/server/bin/my-executable.sh"

bash ${EXE} start -p ${PORT} -h ${HOSTS}
```

Now when I am running this shell script it is giving me an error: `expr: non-numeric argument`. If I hard-code the value (which has shown as the commented code), it works.

Following is the my-prop.properties:

```
PORT=myPort
HOSTS=myHosts
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are multiple such key value pairs in the file and want to filter only `PORT` and `HOST` do a process-substitution as below

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

propFile="${HOME}/my-prop.properties"
scriptPath="${HOME}/server/bin/my-executable.sh"

while read -r port; read -r  host; do 
    bash "$scriptPath" start -p "$port" -h "$host"
done < <(awk -F= '$1=="PORT" || $1=="HOSTS"{print $2}' "$propFile")
```

---

The below would work only if there are those two key-value pairs in the properties file.

Why the round about way to achieve such a simple task. You can do this in `bash` with input re-direction on the properties file with setting `IFS` on `=` and  just read the second word containing the host and port values.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

propFile="${HOME}/my-prop.properties"
scriptPath="${HOME}/server/bin/my-executable.sh"

while IFS== read -r _ port; IFS== read -r _ host; do 
    bash "$scriptPath" start -p "$port" -h "$host"
done < "$propFile"
```

This works under an assumption that you have *only* the two lines in the properties file as shown. If needed you can print the values of host and port before calling the actual script.

Comment: Hi, actually I have some other key=value in the properties file which will be used for different operations, which are not showing in the original post.

Comment: @TapasBose: Refer my update in the first part of the answer

Comment: Hi, thank you for your prompt response, but unfortunately, it is still throwing the same error, `expr: non-numeric argument` for the solution 1 and 2 both.

Comment: @TapasBose: Either you are not providing all the information you have (or) you are not executing the script the right way. It worked fine

Comment: Hi, it is bloody windows which not create linux file properly. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @TapasBose: Glad you found it useful. Convert Windows DOS style endings to Linux file using `dos2unix`